# Can't paste directory from Windows to Lubuntu over RDP

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, copy-paste

I have my windows 10 laptop and a RDP connection to Lubuntu 20.04 which is running in vmware-sphere.

Clipboard is selected in RDP session and vmtools are installed. I can copy&paste text and single file just fine. However I can't copy a directory from Windows to the Lubuntu machine.

I also tried with a different file manage than default, Thunar file manager and same behavior. this one however says when pasting a directory "There is nothing in the clipboard to paste".

When I select files and folder at the same time only the files get pasted.

It is driving me crazy. And hints what might be the cause? Which log to check (didn't find anything yet)?